# Как использовать цикл с embed.add_field в discord.py

Tags: python, discord

У меня есть эмбед в дискорд боте, в который нужно добавлять строчки с именами и их значениями. Хотел использовать цикл for, но он не работает

```
embed = discord.Embed(
        description = f'{user.mention}, вот курсы местных валют',
        color = user.color
    )
embed.set_author(name='Биржа')
for name, value in currencies.items():
    embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=False) #Вот здесь код перестает работать
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего у вас в переменной `currencies`, которую вы не предоставили, хранятся не только строковые объекты, в то время, как параметры `name` и `value` из `embed.add_field` принимают только тип `str`

Скорее всего достаточно преобразовывать все в строку:

```py
embed.add_field(name=str(name), value=str(value), inline=False)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### [**`embed.add_field(*, name, value, inline=True)`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.add_field)